# Incremental backups of Subversion repositories

Tags: backup, unix, bash, svn, command-line-interface

I have two SVN repositories, `svn_rep1` and `svn_rep2`. I want to back them up to a remote server, with an incremental backup daily and a full backup monthly.

How I can write a bash shell script to do this operation? I ask you because I do not have time to search on my own.

Comment: -1 Because time is a limited resource for everybody.

Comment: this is explained it the SVN server documentation quite clearly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) for 1-to-1-copies and [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) for incremental encrypted backups.